# Accessing Properties of Parent Backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, javascript, javascript-framework

I have a backbone view that calls to a sub-view:

```
  lr.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#map'),
    foo: "bar",
    initialize: function() {
      var that = this;
      _.bindAll(this, "render", "addAllEvents", "addOneEvent");
      this.collection = new lr.Events();
      this.collection.fetch({
        success:  function(resp) {
          that.render();
          that.addAllEvents();
        }
      });   
    },

    addAllEvents: function() {
      this.collection.each(this.addOneEvent);
    },

    addOneEvent: function(e) {
      var ev = new lr.EventView({ 
        model:  e
      });
    },

    render: function() {
    } 
  });
```

Here is the sub-view:

```
  lr.EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      console.log(lr.MapView.foo); // will console.log 'undefined' 
    },
    render: function() {
    }
  });
```

I'd like to be able to access properties the parent view within the sub-view, but it isn't working with the above code.  For example, how can I access the 'foo' variable within the sub-view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lr.MapView` is a "class", everything that `Backbone.View.extend` builds will be in `lr.MapView.prototype`, not in `lr.MapView`. Run this with the console open and you'll see whats going on:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({ foo: 'bar' });
console.log(MapView);
console.log(MapView.prototype);
console.log(MapView.prototype.foo);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DnvR5/

If you're only going to have a single MapView then you can refer to `lr.MapView.prototype.foo` everywhere:

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, "render");
  console.log(lr.MapView.prototype.foo);
}
```

Note that *everywhere* includes within `lr.MapView` instances so your `foo` will act like a "class variable" from non-prototype based OO languages.

The right way to do this is to use an instance variable for `foo` and pass the parent view instance to the sub-view instances when they're created:

```
// In MapView
addOneEvent: function(e) {
  var ev = new lr.EventView({
    model: e,
    parent: this
  });
}

// In EventView
initialize: function(options) {
  _.bindAll(this, "render");
  this.parent = options.parent; // Or use this.options.parent everywhere.
  console.log(this.parent.foo); 
}
```

Or better, add an accessor method to `MapView`:

```
_foo: 'bar',
foo: function() { return this._foo }
```

and use that method in `EventView`:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    // ...
    console.log(this.parent.foo());
}
```

Proper encapsulation and interfaces are a good idea even in JavaScript.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you.  Why is the accessor method approach preferable to the other alternative you mention?

Comment: @AdamVickers: The presence of an accessor signals to the outside world that `foo()` is part of MapView's public interface and the lack of a mutator indicates that outsider's aren't supposed to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but could you try something like this in `MapView`:

```
addOneEvent: function(e) {
    var that = this,
        ev = new lr.EventView({ 
            model:  e,
            parentView = that
        });
}
```

And then access it like this:

```
lr.EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      console.log(this.parentView.foo);
    },
    render: function() {
    }
  });
```